# How to return an arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist

I would like to return an arraylist from a non-class method in java, i have searched around but found nothing so far.

```
{
     int d=e.length();
     ArrayList list2 = new ArrayList();
     for (int i=0;i<d;i++)
     {
         list2.add('_');
     }
     return list2;
}
```

Thanks alot!

Comment: Looks like you are returning it already in your code. What's the actual problem?

Comment: What is a *non-class method* in Java? Every method in Java belongs to a class.

Comment: Non-class method? Please clarify. Do you mean a static method? And where's the method's signature?

Comment: That doesn't make sense, please post all the code.

Comment: Is that an initializer block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is put the return type in the signature, and then return the list

```
public class Example {
    // a static method
    public static List someStaticMethod(){
       // create and return a List
    }

    // this method is not static
    public List someMethod(){
       // create and return a List
    }

}
```

Note that because `ArrayList` extends `List` you can make the return type either one of those.

`List` is more generic, you can return *any type of list*.  This is useful because if you want to change the internal list that you use (say change from `ArrayList` to `LinkedList`) you won't have to change your API everywhere you use the method.

However, if you use a list implementation that has its own methods that are not defined by the `List` interface, you won't be able to access those methods when you get the list back from your method, unless you either cast (ewe) or specify the exact return type.

Comment: I haven't got the chance to test this yet, but i believe it is working. FYI, there was some error in my question, and i'm surprised i still managed to get a correct answer. thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

All methods must be either static or instance methods; owned by the class or one of its instances. It's not like C or C++ where you can have functions that are outside of a class altogether.

However, you can do a static import.

```
public class UtilClass {
    public static ArrayList getList() { ... return someList; }
}

import static UtilClass.getList;
```

That will let you more or less treat it like that. However, it must be *defined* as part of a class, and be static.

**EDIT: I forgot to make getList static in the example.**

Comment: So presumably the getList() method needs to be declared static for this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks like a [groovy](http://groovy.codehaus.org/) [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29) - maybe you should try that instead.

Comment: sorry, error there. i meant non-main class.

Answer (score 0):

Your method definition should be something like this.

```
public ArrayList<Character> getCharList(String e)
{    
    int d = e.length();
    // as of Java 1.5, generic collections are available
    ArrayList<Character> list2 = new ArrayList<Character>();
    for (int i=0;i<d;i++) {
        list2.add(new Character('_'));
    }
    return list2;
}
```

I assumed you were calling your length() method for a String. Please adapt to your situation.

To then get your list, do:

```
String e = "a string";
ArrayList<Character> myList = myClass.getCharList(e);
```

Answer (score 0):

Any method that isn't `void` can return any type of data, however, you can only return types the method allows. For example, a method beginning with `public int` can only return an `int` value. To return an ArrayList, your method must include `ArrayList` in the declaration, like so:

```
public ArrayList thisReturnsAnArrList(ArrayList list) {
    return list; //'list' is of the type 'ArrayList'
}
```

However, you can be more lenient and have a method return a `List`. Since multiple classes inherit from `List` (i.e. `ArrayList` and `LinkedList`), you can return any value that extends `List`.